# Bash: is there a way for program/script to run on foreground at specific timing

Tags: bash, scripts

As the above question, is there any program that we can use to run another program/script at foreground.

I know that I can run a program as background job at specific timing using at.

```
at 09:00 -f bashscript.sh
```

What essentially I need is quite like a timer to execute the program/script at certain timing interval..

does it mean I will have to write a program or script that will execute when system clock teach some particular count

Thanks

Comment: Foreground of...?

Comment: @muru: foreground of terminal...ie the  program will run as like as a command line run

Comment: Say you have three terminals open, and maybe an SSH connection from somewhere else that is also in a terminal in another system. Which terminal? Or should this open a new terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. However, you need to be sure of the ID of the terminal (LINE) you want to output to.

This can be found by running this command in the current terminal:

```
$ who -mH
NAME     LINE         TIME             COMMENT
am       pts/0        2023-10-19 09:07 (172.17.0.2)
```

You can also get a complete list of all terminal connections by omitting the `-m`:

```
$ who -H
NAME     LINE         TIME             COMMENT
am       pts/0        2023-10-19 09:07 (172.17.0.2)
am       pts/1        2023-10-08 14:14 (tmux(202201).%0)
am       pts/2        2023-10-08 14:14 (tmux(202201).%1)
am       pts/3        2023-10-08 14:14 (tmux(202201).%2)
```

If LINE shows `ttyX` (replace X with a number), it's a direct connection. If LINE shows `pts/X`, it's a remote connection.

Now you need some clever way to figure out which terminal you write to. I can't advice you on that, since this will depend on your situation.

However, in my case, I know that `pts/3` in `tmux` is the terminal window I'm presented to first, so I can write a script that writes output to this terminal.

A simple example here would be to have `neofetch` run every hour. You then add this line to your crontab:

```
0  *  *  *  * neofetch > pts/3
```

In this way, the output of `neofetch` (run by crontab) will be directed to `pts/3`, and thus displayed in that particular terminal.